# Is this linq syntax query correct?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a select query joining multiple tables using Linq. Could somebody please kindly check for me and tell me if the syntax is wrong or something? Because, i checked that the parameter is passed, but after a breakpoint at the query, it skips another breakpoint in the foreach loop and directly goes to the return statement. Why is this happening?

```
var query = from po in dbb.prescription
            join pv in dbb.patient_visit on po.refid equals pv.pvid
            join pod in dbb.prescription_dtls on po.psid equals pod.psid
            join d in dbb.drugs on pod.dgid equals d.dgid
            join a in dbb.admissions on po.refid equals a.adid
            where (pv.paid == medPaid || a.paid == medPaid) &&
                  (po.status == "Pending") && (po.flag == null) &&
                  (po.TCM == false) && (po.EntBy == medUserID)
            orderby pod.UpdOn descending
            select new { pod.psid, pod.dgid, po.status, d.duom };
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult SetPrescOrderMyList(string medUserID, string medPaid, string medPvid, string medPsid, string medDgid, string medDoctor, string medType, float medMeasurement, float medTimes, float medDays, string medMeals, string medMorning, string medNight, string medWhenNecessary, string medHours, string medOtherInstruction)
{
    vmConsultation Patient = new vmConsultation();

    Patient.SetPrescriptionOrderMyList(medPaid, medPvid, medPsid, medDgid, medDoctor);
    Patient.LoadPrescriptionOrderList = Patient.GetPrescriptionOrderList(medUserID, medPaid, medPvid);

    return Json(Patient, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm actually trying to return rows of data from given query using ajax after inserting it in the database. But it didnt return anything. It skipped the whole foreach loop in the query.

Comment: @GiladGreen do you mean the controller?

Comment: The debugger behaviour sounds like your query just didn't return anything. Keep in mind that the enumerable actually runs when it's being enumerated. As for whether the syntax is wrong, I'd say the compiler is your friend here. If it doesn't complain, it's correct. Of course, whether it actually does what you *want it to* is a different question.

Comment: *skipped the whole foreach loop* I can't see any foreach loop in your code. Also is truly difficult to understand what do you expect to achieve inside your controller without seeing your `vmConsultation` class

Comment: If a LINQ query compiles and runs the *syntax* is correct. We can't possibly judge whether it's *logically* correct. My guess would be that some joins should be outer joins. And I'd recommend to use navigation properties instead of joins wherever possible.

Comment: If the body of the not-shown foreach is skipped then the query resulted in an empty sequence. So either (1) any one of the several sequences mentioned in your query are empty, or (2) they are not empty but there are no matching elements between the sequences in the joins, or (3) there are no elements which match your where clause.

Comment: @GertArnold How to do using navigation properties?